# Getting "JSONDecodeError" while loading a json in Python

Tags: python

I have gone through various suggestions in various Stackoverflow posts, but none of the suggestions worked so far.

Below is my code:

```
with open("entvpndeviceusage.json","r") as f:
  data = f.read()

d = json.loads(data)
```

& even if i do `d = json.load(f).decode('utf-8')`, it fails with the same below error.

```
  File "C:\Users\611840750\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

You can see the file here: https://files.fm/u/3maf9dp9

---

Partial File content

---

```
#Datasource :entvpndeviceusage

[
    {
        "timestamp": "2018-04-04T11:45:06.620Z",
        "result": {

            "dimensions": [
                "SOURCENSG_DN",
                "DOMAIN",
                "APPID",
                "QUERY",
                "ENTERPRISENAME",
                "DOMAIN_SPECID",
                "ENT_SPECID",
                "SOURCENSG",
                "DOMAIN_DN"
            ],
            "metrics": [
                "INGRESSMB",
                "TOTALMB",
                "EGRESSMB"
            ],
            "events": [
                {
                    "segmentId": "entvpndeviceusage_2018-04-04T11:00:00.000Z_2018-04-04T12:00:00.000Z_2018-04-04T10:00:00.368Z_26",
                    "offset": 0,
                    "event": {
                        "timestamp": "2018-04-04T11:45:06.620Z",
                        "DOMAIN": "AC_PHILIPS ELECTRONICS NEDERLAND B_V__0001_31798",
                        "APPID": "904ac61a-fd4b-4a16-bf4a-4cf0671fd6e4",
                        "ENTERPRISENAME": "PHILIPS ELECTRONICS NEDERLAND B_V_",
                        "ENT_SPECID": "bdbd9597-77a6-403a-bcce-a7b6cb78c862",
                        "QUERY": "/ENT_DEVICE_USAGE.txt",
                        "DOMAIN_SPECID": "f3d73d15-c50c-4ed8-80bd-510424d88ad1",
                        "SOURCENSG": null,
                        "DOMAIN_DN": "Philips Office",
                        "SOURCENSG_DN": null,
                        "INGRESSMB": 0,
                        "TOTALMB": 2924.72998046875,
                        "EGRESSMB": 2924.72998046875
                    }
                },
                {
                    "segmentId": "entvpndeviceusage_2018-04-04T11:00:00.000Z_2018-04-04T12:00:00.000Z_2018-04-04T10:00:00.368Z_28",
                    "offset": 0,
                    "event": {
                        "timestamp": "2018-04-04T11:45:07.870Z",
                        "DOMAIN": "AC_PHILIPS ELECTRONICS NEDERLAND B_V__0001_31798",
                        "APPID": "b13cb67e-2b79-4fdd-8331-d58c87791df0",
                        "ENTERPRISENAME": "PHILIPS ELECTRONICS NEDERLAND B_V_",
                        "ENT_SPECID": "bdbd9597-77a6-403a-bcce-a7b6cb78c862",
                        "QUERY": "/ENT_DEVICE_USAGE.txt",
                        "DOMAIN_SPECID": "f3d73d15-c50c-4ed8-80bd-510424d88ad1",
                        "SOURCENSG": null,
                        "DOMAIN_DN": "Philips Office",
                        "SOURCENSG_DN": null,
                        "INGRESSMB": 0,
                        "TOTALMB": 0,
                        "EGRESSMB": 0
                    }
                }
                ...
                ...
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Looks like `nsgapptest.json` is empty?

Comment: You might want to post your input data?

Comment: @Rakesh no the json file is not empty..

Answer (score 0):

Even when you write `json.load(open('nsgapptest.json'))` you can load the json value but problem is with your json file
one of the reason of raising `"Expecting value"` is because of empty or invalid json structure
Ex.

```
// valid json structure
[{
    "a": 1
}]

// invalid json structure
[{
    "a": 1
}, ]
```

because of trailing comman it is expecting value and python will throw `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value`

Comment: Thanks for the input, let me validate the json file.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the JSON file contents [here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu). If the JSON is valid and the error still occurs, please post the file here and then I can answer better.

Comment: Pl remove the first two lines in the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering a novice question like this :)