# Decoding custom types from file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, object, decode

I am teaching myself python in stages, and have started using JSON to help my basic little project.
I have an object for a weapon

```
class actionAttack():
    '''
    name    String
    hit     Int            bonus to hit
    dam     Int            damage bonus
    dice    Tuple(0,1)     damage dice xDy
    '''
    def __init__(self, name, hit, dam, diceTuple):
        self.name = name
        self.hit = hit
        self.dam = dam
        self.diceTuple = diceTuple
```

And a JSON file describing a weapon:

```
{
  "__WEAPON__":True,
  "name": "Sword", 
  "hit": 5, 
  "dam": 2, 
  "diceTuple":[2, 6]
}
```

I've created a decoder as per a tutorial I was following and i have the following:

```
import json


def decode_weapon(dct):
    if '__WEAPON__' in dct:
        return actionAttack(dct["name"], dct["hit"], dct["dam"], dct["diceTuple"])
    return dct

with open('data_test.json') as attack_data:
    data = attack_data.read()
    attackDict = json.loads(data, object_hook=decode_weapon)
```

When i compile, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    attackDict = json.loads(data, object_hook=decode_weapon)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 367, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 15 (char 16)
```

Comment: your json structure is invalid validate it at [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) and watch [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687101/7664524) thread if you want to see why such error arises

Comment: `True` is not a valid json object - you probably want `true`. But a nicer way to 'tag' your objects with their type/class might be to use `"__class__" : "Weapon"`, then you will know all your classes will have a "__class__" attribute

Comment: Than you both. @Gahan that solved it.

Comment: @TomDalton, thanks for the great tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`True` is not a valid json object - you probably want `true`.

A nicer way to 'tag' your objects with their type/class might be to use `"__class__" : "weapon"`, then you will know all your classes will have a `"class"` attribute. E.g.

```
{
  "__class__": "weapon",
  "name": "Sword", 
  "hit": 5, 
  "dam": 2, 
  "diceTuple":[2, 6]
}
```

and then:

```
def decode_weapon(dct):
    if dct['__class__'] != 'weapon':
        raise ValueError("Not a valid weapon dictionary")
    return actionAttack(dct["name"], dct["hit"], dct["dam"], dct["diceTuple"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since json comes from java-script and not from Python, the 'True' value is written with a lower case t.

Change 'True' to 'true'.